# Implementing USB OTG dual role device with STM32

Tags: embedded, usb, stm32, usb-otg

I'm using USB OTG periphery of STM32F205 microcontollers. I've already implemented  both host (using HAL and USB Host Library) and device (HAL + USB Device Library) separately. But I'm stuck with automatic mode detection. I couldn't manage to find any example firmware with dual-role USB. STM's examples usaully use onscreen menu or buttons to switch the host/device mode.

The simplest way I see is to configure OTG ID pin as GPIO input and to poll its state. But I believe there a better way for device with a harware OTG.

Does anyone have an idea how should I start with?

Comment: This might be more suited to the [Electronics SE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), unless there is some [specific code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you need help with (if so, please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29560565/edit) to include it).

Comment: This is software-related question. The hardware has been copied from ST's reference designs and now I'm trying to create a firmware to make it work.